# overlapping addresses on a multipoint sub-interface

Tags: networking

When trying to configure a frame relay hub on packet tracer by doing exactly what someone did in GNS3 I encountered an annoying problem:

the guy created a multipoint sub-interface on the 172.16.1.0 /24 network (172.168.1.1) and then created another multipoint sub-interface on the same network (172.168.1.2). when I tried to do that I got the "overlapping network" error, but he didn`t.

is that a packet tracer bug? becuase accroding to the answers on this site - it`s not, I can not create another interface after using the 172.16.1.1-172.16.1.254 range - in the same range. the problem (aside from GNS3 can do it) is that it is absolutely necessary to do that if you want to configure frame-relay full-mesh signle IP hub.

so...what exactly can be done?

thanks ahead 
willow